# Understanding nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

In Rails would it be correct that where ever two tables are connected in a 1:M relationship there should be a corresponding nested route in the routes config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a strict requirements. Routes depends on the logic of your application.

If `Post` belongs to `Blog`, it doesn't mean you can't have a top-level route for `Post` where (for instance) you aggregate all the posts.

It's common to have nested routes in case of a 1:M association because of the logical way resources are accessed. But this is not a strict requirement.